# Which one will suit for complete workflow design Temporal or Cadence

Tags: cadence-workflow, cadence, temporal-workflow

I wanted to design a complete end-to-end workflow orchestration engine.

It has the following requirements

1. **Linear workflow**
2. **Parallel workflow** - I wanted to execute n no of activities parallelly. After validates the results from all the activities I wanted to
   proceed to the next state or will fail the workflow
3. **Batch** - say I have 30 activities to be completed but I want this to be done in a batch fashion. Like if the window size is 5 then I wanted
   to execute 5 activities at a time T. After executing all the activities
   and validates the results will proceed further or fail the workflow.
4. **Loop** - wanted to run an activity infinitely until some condition meets
5. **Child Workflow**
6. **Polling**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All 1-5 are supported easily in Cadence workflow. I am not sure what you mean by `Polling`. If you can provide more details, I will update this answer to help you.

Here is the [sample to execute activities in Leaner+parallel/batch+loop](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/pull/38/files):

```java
  @Override
  public long calculate(long a, long b, long c) {
    LOGGER.info("workflow start...");

    long result = 0;

    // Async.invoke takes method reference and activity parameters and returns Promise.
    Promise<Long> ab = Async.function(activities::multiple, a, b);
    Promise<Long> ac = Async.function(activities::multiple, a, c);
    Promise<Long> bc = Async.function(activities::multiple, b, c);

    // Promise#get blocks until result is ready.
    this.abPlusAcPlusBc = result = ab.get() + ac.get() + bc.get();

    // waiting 30s for a human input to decide the factor N for g(n), based on a*b+a*c+b*c
    // the waiting timer is durable, independent of workers' liveness
    final boolean received = Workflow.await(Duration.ofMinutes(2), () -> this.factorForGn > 1);
    if (!received) {
      this.factorForGn = 10;
    }

    long fi_1 = 0; // f(0)
    long fi_2 = 1; // f(1)
    this.currentG = 1; // current g = f(0)*f(0) + f(1)*f(1)
    long i = 2;

    for (; i < this.factorForGn; i++) {
      // get next fibonacci number
      long fi = fi_1 + fi_2;
      fi_2 = fi_1;
      fi_1 = fi;

      this.currentG += activities.multiple(fi, fi);
    }

    result += this.currentG;
    return result;
  }
```

And this is the [sample of using ChildWorkflow](https://github.com/uber/cadence-java-samples/blob/master/src/main/java/com/uber/cadence/samples/hello/HelloChild.java).